# Code in genetic algorithm for non linear simultaneous equations

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I need to solve three nonlinear simultaneous equations

```
y1 = exp(-(r1 +r2)*t)
y2 = (r1/((r3+r4)-(r1+r2)))*[exp(-[r1+r2]*t) - exp(-[r3+r4]*t)]
y3 = (r1/((r5+r6)-(r1+r2)))*[exp(-[r1+r2]*t) - exp(-[r5+r6]*t)]
```

where `y1`, `y2`, `y3` and `t` is known and `i` aim to find `r1`, `r2`... `r6`.
I need to do this using genetic algorithm. Can someone provide me teh codz.

Comment: possible duplicate of [designing fitness function in genetic algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633664/designing-fitness-function-in-genetic-algorithm)

Comment: You asked that question already. Your candor in "gimme the codez" is admirable, but StackOverflow generally doesn't do that for you.

Comment: ...unless you provide a bounty, but with only 11 points, I guess that's out of the question. And besides, coding a GA is fun!

Comment: is this the exact same question? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633664/designing-fitness-function-in-genetic-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

genetic algorithm can't solve such problems completely
genetic algorithm can give you a range for y1, y2, y3
for more information see this paper
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.2373&rep=rep1&type=pdf